# ¿Es posible utilizar 2 Layout en 1 Activity, en Xamarin.Android VS2015?

Tags: android-layout, visual-studio-2015, activity, xamarin.android

```
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListadoDeEstilos);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DialogInput);
        Inicializar();
        lstEstilos = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstEstilos);

        LoadEstilo();
        lstEstilos.ItemLongClick += LstEstilos_ItemLongClick;

    }
```

Intente poner los dos SetContentView, pero me marca error cuando trato de utilizar algún control de los del segundo Layout

Comment: Y cual es el objetivo de tener 2 layouts para una sola activity?

Comment: @Einer Estoy utilizando un FragmentTransaction, y pues se me hace más sencillo tener los controles de los dos layouts en un sólo activity, que tener 2 activitys y pasar valores entre ellos

Comment: Tendrías que introducir dentro del Layout de tu activity dos FrameLayout e inflarlos con tu FragmentManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Es posible utilizar 2 Layout en 1 Activity?

**No es posible cargarlos en una Activity ya que mediante `SetContentView()` únicamente se puede cargar un layout.**

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
   }
```

---

Si deseas cargar uno o varios layouts que definen una distinta interfaz, en realidad este es el objetivo de los [**Fragments**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/implementing-with-fragments/)

> Un Fragmento es una parte de la interfaz de usuario o comportamiento
>   de una aplicación que puede colocarse en una Actividad.

Revisa el documento [**Administración de Fragmentos**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/managing-fragments)